# How to do a grouped distinct in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have something working in plain simpel loops but I want to know how to do it with LINQ, if possible.

I don't even know how to describe what i want to do. But stack overflow wants me to do so in words instead of with an example, so this is me tricking it...

**The classes** (stripped down)

```
public class Product
{

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryGroup> CategoryGroups { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryGroup
{
    public int CategoryGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**What I want to do**

From

```
Product 1
    CategoryGroup 1
        Category 11
        Category 12
        Category 13
    CategoryGroup 2
        Category 21
        Category 22

Product 2
    Category Group 1
        Category 11
        Category 14
    Category Group 2
        Category 21
    Category Group 3
        Category 31
```

To

```
Category Group 1
    Category 11
    Category 12
    Category 13
    Category 14
Category Group 2
    Category 21
    Category 22
Category Group 3
    Category 31
```

**The working code**

```
var categoryGroups = new List<CategoryGroup>();
foreach (var product in products)
{
    foreach (var categoryGroup in product.CategoryGroups)
    {
        var group = categoryGroups.SingleOrDefault(cg => cg.CategoryGroupId == categoryGroup.CategoryGroupId);
        if (group == null)
        {
            group = new CategoryGroup {
                Categories = new List<Category>(),
                CategoryGroupId = categoryGroup.CategoryGroupId,
                Name = categoryGroup.Name
            };
            categoryGroups.Add(group);
        }

        foreach (var category in categoryGroup.Categories)
        {
            if (group.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == category.CategoryId))
            {
                continue;
            }
            group.Categories.Add(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code to populate the sample data - to make it easier for those trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query to get all the different category groups

```
   var categoryGroups = products.SelectMany(g => g.CategoryGroups)
                                     .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryGroupId)
                                     .Select(y => new { CategoryGroupId = y.Key,
                                                    Categories = y.SelectMany(category => category.Categories).Distinct().ToList()                                          });
```

To eliminate duplicate categories you will have to modify your Category object to implement the IEquatable interface as follows

```
 public class Category : IEquatable<Category>
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Category other)
    {
        //Check whether the compared object is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return CategoryId.Equals(other.CategoryId) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field. 
        int hashProductCode = CategoryId.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

Implementing the interface allows the Distinct() call in LINQ to compare the list of objects and eliminate duplicates.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do many subselections through SelectMany:

```
var result = products
            .SelectMany(x => x.CategoryGroups)
            .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryGroupId)
            .Select(x => new CategoryGroup
                         {
                             Categories = x.SelectMany(y => y.Categories)
                                           .Distinct(y => y.CategoryId)
                                           .OrderBy(y => y.CategoryId)
                                           .ToList(),
                             CategoryGroupId = x.Key,
                             Name = x.Values.First().Name
                         })
            .OrderBy(x => x.CategoryGroupId)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Many errors inside the `Select` after `GroupBy`: `x.Values`, `x.CategoryGroupId`, `x.Name` (no such members), `Distinct(y => y.CategoryId)`(no such method overload)

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: I get the following error `IGrouping<int,CategoryGroup> does not contain a definition for 'Values'`